# Cannot get methods in a class

Tags: c#

Im trying to get the method of my class in a Form Windows App

```
namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{ 
  public partial class fireEdit : Form
  {
    enforcementClass myClass;

    public fireEdit()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //Initialize the class
        myClass = new enforcementClass();
        //no suggestions like my method Test() in a class
        myClass.  
    }
  }
}
```

This is my class

Is there a missing constructor in my class or references?

```
class enforcementClass
{
    public void Test() {
        Console.Write("TEST");
    }

}
```

Comment: Rebuild your project and restart Visual Studio. It's probably Intellisense bugging out. Failing that, you have two `enforcementClass` classes (in different namespaces, presumably the one referenced by `fireEdit` isn't in a namespace, is in `WindowsFormsApp1`, or is in a namespace referenced with `using`)

Comment: I've already tried that but still the same only gives suggestions the `Reference` and `Equal`

Comment: Click on `enforcementClass` in your `fireEdit` constructor and press `F12`.

Comment: I just figure out there is a missing `namespace` in my class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I just figure what is wrong, there is a missing namespace in a class

```
//This fixed my problem the namespace
namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{ 
  class enforcementClass
  {
      public void Test() {
         Console.Write("TEST");
      }
 }
}
```

Comment: If that was the case, you would have had a compiler error (which you neglected to mention in your question).

Comment: I have no error receive even in a debugger and my application runs perfectly without a namespace in a class

Comment: **If** the namespace fixed it, then before you added the namespace the `enforcementClass myClass` would have resulted in a compiler error.

Answer (score -1):

Is this in the same Assembly (and namespace) as your Windows Form app?

```cs
class enforcementClass
{
    public void Test() {
        Console.Write("TEST");
    }

}
```

Classes without an access modifier default to `internal`.

REF: [Class and Struct Accessibility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/access-modifiers#class-and-struct-accessibility)